# I Can't able to build my project in TFS

Tags: tfs

The build gets stuck and there is no progress.The most important situation here is that, as you can see in the red rectangle, it says the source version of the code is “T”.

[image]

Comment: Is that a XAML build?

Comment: yes it is xaml build

Comment: Restart the build controller and see if that helps

Comment: But It may affect the other project in that collection.

Comment: Area other builds running properly?

Comment: I’m suspecting something is preventing the build to get the latest version of the code, so the build gets stuck and the packages are not generated. This is happening for other two build definitions as well. We have not modified these definitions since 1 year ago and there were working fine until now, when we discovered this issue.

Comment: When "T" is specified as the source version, the build task will execute "tf get /version:T" command that **will get the latest version** of your source code. Refer to tf get command for details: `/version:versionspec

Specifies the maximum version, or the minimum and the maximum versions, to display in the history data. The default is /version:T (the latest version).` So it's using the  latest version and this is not related to issue.  To narrow down the issue, you could also try to build a specific changeset instead of latest version.